# How to check the logged user information?

Tags: c#, asp.net

My code is to check the logged user and retrieve his data as Image, Name, Department as this application work on network. I tested my code and it worked well at **Localhost** but when I deployed on the company server it doesn't work.

The authentication is windows .

```
DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher();
searcher.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;
string UserName = Page.User.Identity.Name;
searcher.Filter = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "(sAMAccountName={0})", UserName.Split('\\')[1]);
SearchResult findUser = searcher.FindOne();
if (findUser != null)
{
    DirectoryEntry user = findUser.GetDirectoryEntry();
    LoggedUser = user.Properties["displayName"].Value.ToString();
    LoggedEmail = user.Properties["mail"].Value.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Put some logging in your code so you can find out which line of code is causing your error.

Comment: Piece of advice add exception logging to your code to prevent future headaches, trying to guess where the issue is will not help you solve your problem. Modifying production code in order to add logging when an issue arises is very poor practice, look into enterprise library logging examples to enhance your solution.

Comment: When I see a question saying "it doesn't work" without explaining *in which way* it doesn't work, I'll vote to close as "lacks sufficient information to diagnose the problem" or "unclear what you're asking" 9 times out of 9. "It doesn't work" doesn't give anyone a starting point for examining the problem. Explain what results you're getting and how they differ from the intended results, and include any error messages you received.